# ioctl error when trying to beep with a duration and frequency

Tags: c, linux, console, beep

I'm trying to make a beep sound with a frequency and a duration, i'm using ioctl and a file with the console path (I think it is right, i'm using debian 6, by the way) but i don't know why it doesn't work. The code reaches the line ioctl, but it doesn't beep. Im working in a Virtual Machine. The drivers should not be the problem because i have installed my own driver that controls the keyboard leds and makes no problem.

(I have followed this example: http://linuxplayer.org/2010/04/beep-your-pc-speaker-in-linux)

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>

int bip;
#define consolepath "/dev/console"
//#define consolepath "/dev/tty0"

void beep (int freq, int dur){
    int aux;
    if ( (bip = open(consolepath, 'w')) == -1 ) {
        printf ("console unreachable/dev/console!\n" );
    }else{
        //fprintf(bip, "%c[10;%d]%c[11;%d]\a", ESC, freq, ESC, dur);    //Another different try
        ioctl(bip, KDMKTONE, (dur<<16 | 1193180/freq));

        close(bip);

    }
}
```

Comment: check the `errno` value from the failed ioctl call.

Comment: the ioctl call, returns 0, so it looks like it would be doing it well

Comment: Turn your speakers on and turn the volume/s up above zero:)

Comment: My speakers were turned on, but thanks :) Is there another path where i could make sounds with a frequency and duration?

Comment: is the freq in the audible range? 10 to 10-20kHx?

Comment: 'freq = 440;' 'dur =500;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my OS, i was executing Debian 6 in VMWare Workstation, and the port mapping is not well done, so i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that fixes your problem, but the "oflag" argument given
to `open()` should be `O_WRONLY` or perhaps `O_RDWR`, but not the character `'w'`.

Comment: Yeah, i know, i've changed it but as expected it still doesn't work.